# Pourquoi app et plus appli ?

Tags: abréviations

De mon *époque* on disait `appli` en Technos de l'Information, en guise d’abréviation d'une `application`. Mais l'anglais dit `app`. Comme il n'y a pas de petites économies, et que trois lettres c'est plus court que cinq, alors la communauté française en ligne semble avoir emprunté `app` à l'anglais. Est-ce justifié ? 
*Perso* je dis toujours `appli`, suis-je "old game" ?

Comment: Je ne sais pas si je suis dans le vrai, mais j'emploie la demie mesure : je parle d'app pour les applications sur les smartphones. Dans mon travail (je suis informaticien), je parle encore d'applis (web ou native). Parler d'une "app web" ou d'une "app native" ça me ferait bizarre :)

Comment: "Old school" pas "Old game" :)

Comment: Oui je sais, d'où mes guillemets.

Answer (score 4):

Le passage de `appli` à `app` tient plus d'une volonté d'utiliser le mot anglais que d'une économie de 2 lettres.

C'est de plus en plus fréquent (surtout en informatique, en business etc.) d'utiliser des mots anglais pour des termes où on a déjà un mot français (mais bon je t'apprends rien là-dessus je pense)

L'`App Store` d'Apple a aussi dû participer à amener le mot dans le vocabulaire des gens.

Answer (score 3):

Selon moi, le déclencheur a été l'[App Store](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store) d'Apple. Une recherche sur Google Trends ([app, appli, application, logiciel](https://trends.google.fr/trends/explore?cat=5&date=all&q=app,appli,application,logiciel)) indique que le terme a décollé à partir de 2009, soit six mois après l'ouverture de ladite boutique en ligne. Cela conforte l'idée qu'une *app* concerne d'abord les téléphones. On peut noter aussi qu'*appli* est très rare même vis-à-vis d'*application* ou de *logiciel*.

Comment: "appli est très rare" => selon Google trends ? Ref. requise svp.

Comment: Oui selon Google Trends. La référence est le lien hypertexte dans ma réponse. Je n'ai pas recoupé avec d'éventuelles autres sources.

Answer (score 1):

> Perso je dis toujours appli, suis-je "old game" ?

Oui et non. Dans le milieu technique informatique que je côtoie, "appli" est l'abrévation la plus utilisée pour les applications non mobiles (web, desktop) et reste même assez répandue pour désigner une application pour smartphone, surtout dans l'expression *"appli mobile"*.

Dans le grand public, il faudrait faire une étude mais il y a des chances pour qu' "app" ait pris les devants, en effet.

Comment: Et comme quoi les citoyens globaux ont de l'influence : mon fils, Franco-Australien, me répond "app" quand je lui parle d'appli...